# Convert character to time in R ( "2019-09-24D00:00:03.384309000" )

Tags: r

I am trying to convert some text data to time. I know of methods to convert `2019-09-24 00:00:03` into time format but I want to convert higher frequency data to time.

Some of the observations looks like:

```
 [1] "2019-09-24D00:00:03.384309000" "2019-09-24D00:00:03.404018000"
 [3] "2019-09-24D00:00:03.408065000" "2019-09-24D00:00:03.552361000"
 [5] "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000" "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000"
 [7] "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000" "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000"
```

I found some Python code which can convert this data:

```
data[‘timestamp’] = data.timestamp.map(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t[:-3], “%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f”))
```

Data:

```
data <- c("2019-09-24D00:00:03.384309000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.404018000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.408065000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.552361000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.572690000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.614967000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.656928000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.711825000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.711825000", 
"2019-09-24D00:00:03.711825000", "2019-09-24D00:00:03.711825000"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lubridate` to parse it correctly

```
library(lubridate)
out <- ymd_hms(data)
format(head(out), '%OS6')
#[1] "03.384309" "03.404017" "03.408064" "03.552361" "03.572690" "03.572690"
```

It parses the milliseconds, but the `print` method `formats` the output to print nicely on screen.  If we want to see whether the milliseconds is already there,

---

Or with `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime(data)
```

Comment: That works but does not take into account the `miliseconds`. Should I just store them in a separate column?

Comment: @user8959427  It is taking into account but it is only printing it differently

Comment: @user8959427  You can check `format(ymd_hms(data), '%OS6')
 [1] "03.384309" "03.404017", ..`

Comment: Thanks! that is something I was unaware about.

Comment: Is there somewhere in the global options I can turn "on" the miliseconds?

Comment: @user8959427  You can use the `options` `op <- options(digits.secs=6)`

Answer (score 0):

Check out `asPOSIXct()`. To figure out the right `format` args, take a look into `?strptime`.

```
res <- as.POSIXct(data, format="%FD%R:%OS")
head(res, 3)
# [1] "2019-09-24 00:00:03.384309 CEST" "2019-09-24 00:00:03.404017 CEST"
# [3] "2019-09-24 00:00:03.408065 CEST"
class(res)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```